# Simplify nested HTML with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am cleaning up arbitrary HTML for printing it. I don't need to preserve the structure because I control the CSS selectors and a simpler tree seems to cause fewer errors.

Is there an idiomatic way in Beautifulsoup that will allow me to reduce nesting, or do I just need to do the hard yards and manage the tree myself?

As a *very* simplified example, can I make this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = """
<article>
    <div>
        <div>
            <section>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Hello</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p>World!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

return this:

```html
<article>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World!</p>
</article>
```

I'm open to non-bs4 methods too, this just seems to be the cleanest way to deal with HTML.

Comment: Why `world!` 2 times?

Comment: because I'm an idiot!

Comment: Hahahaha!!! BTW, is the first tag always an `article` tag? Or can it be anything?

Comment: In most cases, an article, but I might be doing this at different scales. Ultimately, always an article, but the markup form some sources (e.g. blogspot) will make your eyes bleed.

Comment: Check out my answer. U can make slight modifications to it to suit ur needs.

Comment: Did my answer help u?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = """
<article>
    <div>
        <div>
            <section>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Hello</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p>World!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc,'html5lib')

txt = soup.find_all()

final = ""
parents = []
lst = []
main_elements = []

for elem in txt:
    if elem.find_all() == []:
        lst = []
        main_elements.append(elem)
        for p in elem.parents:
            lst.append(p.name)
        parents.append(lst)

for index,lstt in enumerate(parents):
    if 'body' not in lstt:
        parents.remove(lstt)
        main_elements.pop(index)

final_parents = []

final_parents = [parents[x][parents[x].index('body')-1] for x in range(len(parents))]

for index,tag in enumerate(final_parents):
    final += (f"<{tag}>")
    final += (str(main_elements[index]))
    final += (f"</{tag}>")

print(final)
```

Output:

```
<article>
<p>Hello</p>
</article>
<article>
<p>World!</p>
</article>
```

If you want the output in the format that you have specified in ur question, you can replace the last `for` loop with this:

```
final += (f"<{final_parents[0]}>")

for index,tag in enumerate(final_parents):
    final += (str(main_elements[index]))

final += (f"</{final_parents[0]}>")

print(final)
```

Output:

```
<article>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>World!</p>
</article>
```